# Does anybody knows what is this: ?v=c2f3f489a005

Tags: wordpress, url, seo

That appears at the end of URLs.

I tried Google search but nothing, I want to know what caused that. Does it affect SEO?

Web with wordpress/elementor/woocomerce and plugins

Answer (score 0):

As per looking into your Web plugins instruction above, You used **WooCommerce** plugins and It may casing with **WooCommerce** settings, You can disable that by follow below instruction,

1. First you need to login to your WordPress admin area and Go To the **WooCommerce** » **Settings** page.
2. Go Under the General tab, you need to scroll down to see "**Default customer location**" option.
3. It would be set to ‘**Geolocate (with page caching support)**’. You need to change it to either ‘**No location by default**’ or ‘**Shop base address**’ or '**Geolocate**'.
4. Don’t forget to click on the save changes button to store your settings.
5. If you are using a caching plugin, then you will need to clear your WordPress cache. After that you can visit your website, and the version string(?v=) will disappear from your WordPress URLs.